# Determine what tree bank type can come next

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp, penn-treebank

I am use `Apache NLP` and its `POSTaggerME`. I have it breaking down words into their `Penn Treebank tag set` values. Is there any functionality out there (doesn't have to be in Apache NLP) that lets you know what kind of word can come next using the English language structure and semantics?

For example, I have sentence `"Most large "` which breaks down to `JJS` and `JJ`. Or an `Adjective, superlative`, and an `Adjective`. What I want to know, is using the structure of the English language, if there is a tool that can tell me if something like an `NNS`, or a `Noun, plural` can come next and the sentence is still valid?

Comment: Try http://erg.delph-in.net, one of the English parser stands the time and comparable to the great [Parsey McParseface](parsey mcparseface). It might not be easy to understand the output unless you go through a course in http://courses.washington.edu/ling567/ though